# How to store weekly time availability in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am programming an appointment system for doctors office. I need to store weekly availability of doctor. Something like this:-

```
        DoctorID | 10AM | 11AM |     12AM  | 1PM | 2PM |    3PM    | 4PM | 
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
 [MON]  5477J    |  1   |  0   | AppointID |   1 |   1 | AppointID | 0   |
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
 [TUE]  5477J    |  0   |  1   | AppointID |   1 |   1 | AppointID | 0   | 
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am storing the time slots as `numeric` `1 implies **avaialble**`   `0 implies **will not be in office**` and if there is an appointment booked then the timeslot will be replaced by `AppointmentID`.

The availability is going to differ each day. My question is How do I store for availability for each day? Should I have 5 rows per weekly schedule. Can someone point me to some simple schema or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: You must normalize your DB.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you only want to track availability per hour and on the hour?  You will never have a situation where they are available from 3:30 to 4:15?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: yes it will always be one hour

Comment: I can almost guarantee that will change.  In my experience even if someone swears on their grandmother a requirement like that will never change, it almost always does.

Comment: @AbeMiessler yup I agree with you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One model I've used in the past is something like this:

```
TABLE [AppointmentBlock]
  - [DoctorID] INT
  - [StartTime] DATETIME
  - [EndTime] DATETIME
  - [IsAvailable] BIT
  - [IsRecurring] BIT
  - [AppointmentID] INT
```

If `[IsRecurring] = 1`, this would represent a block that recurs at the same time every week, and you should assume that start / end times are offsets calculated from the start of the week.

If `[IsRecurring] = 0`, this would just be a one-time occurrence and start / end times are absolute.

So each block in a doctor's schedule is accounted for, even if it doesn't fall precisely on each hour. Some strict business logic needs to be layered on top of this to ensure that no overlaps are created (unless for some reason you want to allow this).

To fit your example to this model you'd have something like this:

```
DoctorID | Start    | End      | IsAvailable | IsRecurring | AppointmentId | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
5477J    | 10AM Mon | 11AM Mon |           1 |           1 |          NULL |
5477J    | 11AM Mon | 12PM Mon |           0 |           1 |          NULL |
5477J    | 12PM Mon |  1PM Mon |           0 |           1 |     AppointID |
5477J    |  1PM Mon |  3PM Mon |           1 |           1 |          NULL |
5477J    |  3PM Mon |  4PM Mon |           0 |           1 |     AppointID |
5477J    |  4PM Mon |  5PM Mon |           0 |           1 |          NULL |
5477J    | 10AM Tue | 11AM Tue |           0 |           1 |          NULL |
5477J    | 11AM Tue | 12PM Tue |           1 |           1 |          NULL |
5477J    | 12PM Tue |  1PM Tue |           0 |           1 |     AppointID |
5477J    |  1PM Tue |  3PM Tue |           1 |           1 |          NULL |
5477J    |  3PM Tue |  4PM Tue |           0 |           1 |     AppointID |
5477J    |  4PM Tue |  5PM Tue |           0 |           1 |          NULL |
```

Comment: +1, This seems like a much better approach than what you are considering.  It will also allow you to schedule appointments that aren't exactly on the hour.

Comment: Admittedly, this is slightly de-normalized since the full meaning of the start / end times depends on the `IsRecurring` flag. I suppose, the alternative would be to create a separate table for recurring and single occurrence blocks.

Comment: But I am not looking for how to store the appointment...I need to store the weekly availability for the doctor..For MON,TUE,WED....

Comment: Notice the `IsAvailable` flag. In my example I assume `IsAvailable = 0` whenever `AppointmentID` is not null. If `IsAvailable = 1`, then the doctor is available for that given block.

Comment: How would you store the initial doctor availability? Say they're available 10am - 1pm monday, and I book them 11am - 12noon, would an initial availability record be Start 10am, End 1pm, and after I book, some processes deletes that record and enters two new ones: 10am - 11am, and 12noon - 1pm? Would this be best asked as a new question?

Comment: Actually, I *think* I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16669342/5783745). Still interested in your ideas. (my very first time exploring such an app, it's providing educational value)